# Django LoginRequiredMixin not working as intented

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-login

The LoginRequiredMixin is not working as intended for the class based view below, I was able to access the webpage regardless of login status, but it should have redirected the unauthorized users to the login page. Where have I gone wrong?

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from django.views.generic import FormView
from .forms import UpdatePortfolio
# Create your views here.

class UpdatePortfolioView(LoginRequiredMixin, FormView):
    login_url = 'users:login'
    redirect_field_name = 'mainpage:update'
    form = UpdatePortfolio
    template_name = 'mainpage/updateportfolio.html'

    def get_object(self):
        # return self.request.user.id
        return self.request.user.pk

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.form_class
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})
```

Comment: Have your tried using `login_url = 'users/login/` instead?

Comment: Yes, I have tried to do so, but I got the same outcome

Answer (score 0):

I think the Problem is Because you Override the Get method... Because the functionality of Redirecting the users will add to the `get` function and you had overridden it
remove it ... and you should know that all the  code in the function is already will be done by the `FormView` You don't have to write it
Read this [Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/)

Comment: It's still not working after removing the get function, whenever I type localhost/mainpage/1/updateportfolio/, I can still access the webpage without any login status. This is my current link under urls.py, `code`(path('<int:pk>/updateportfolio/', mainview.UpdatePortfolioView.as_view(), name='update'))

Answer (score 0):

It's your `redirect_field_name` value.

```
redirect_field_name = 'mainpage:update'
```

The default is:

```
redirect_field_name = 'next'
```